# Where to manually download the JARS from when Maven cannot find a dependency

Tags: maven, jar, maven-dependency

I want to create a Maven webapp sample project on a dev machine without internet, but with access a Nexus repo via the local network. The Nexus repo is years old, so it has *most* dependencies, but not all.

I have set up maven that it uses the local Nexus and then I typed:

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=1.4
```

Maven goes off and downloads what it can from the local Nexus, but then it fails with:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-api:jar:1.0-alpha-16, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:1.2-alpha-7: Failure to find org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-api:jar:1.0-alpha-16

Due to the fact that the machine is not connected to the internet and that I have no control over the Nexus repo (so cannot add jars to it), would need to download the depend JARs for `org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-api` and `org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds` manually (on another internet-connected computer).

*Where on the Internet do I find them?* -- I tried a search on https://jar-download.com/online-maven-download-tool.php. E.g. for `org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-api` I search with  the following the XML snippet:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
   <artifactId>plexus-component-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-alpha-16</version>
</dependency>
```

but this didn't yield any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use copy goal of [dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) for download and copy artifacts:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.3.0:copy \
 -Dartifact=org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-api:1.0-alpha-16:jar \
 -DoutputDirectory=.
```

You can also download manually from Maven Central repository, eg:

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/

Comment: Thanks. The URL is exactly what I was after (because on the machine _with_ internet I don't have Maven installed, so I can't use its copy goal).